# Ember.js: CSS Class Binding breaks if used within {{with}} helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using the following libraries for my `Ember` Project:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 2.0.2
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

I've discovered some strange(?) behaviour when puzzling together a `Handlebars` Template for my `Ember` Application as I wanted to create a CSS class binding within a `{{with}}` block helper. It seems that, somehow, **this** doesn't work as expected:

```
...
{{#with controller.currentData}}
  <div class="mydata-container" {{bind-attr class="this.hasError:error:ok"}}>
    {{this.foo}} - {{this.bar}}
  </div>
{{/with}}
...
```

the `<div/>` will always show something like `data-bindattr-666=666` (number is of course increasing) but the classes will never be 'injected'. (it also makes no difference if I omit the `this` keyword, which also works for displaying the data). If I try to `{{log this.hasError}}` I get the awaited result (`true:false`).

If I write the Template without the `{{with}}` helper, like this:

```
...
<div class="mydata-container" {{bind-attr class="controller.currentData.hasError:error:ok"}}>
    {{controller.currentData.foo}} - {{controller.currentData.bar}}
</div>
...
```

it works as expected.

**Is this a known issue/bug within `Ember`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem isn't with the `{{#with}}` view helper. But because you are declaring the `{{bind-attr class=...}}`, and the `class="mydata-container"` html property in the same time.

If you need to use static classes you have to prefix it with a colon. For example {{bind-attr class=":static-class other-dynamic-classes"}}. This is also documented [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/#toc_static-classes).

Your updated code will be the following:

```
{{#with controller.currentData}}
  <div {{bind-attr class=":mydata-container this.hasError:error:ok"}}>
    {{this.foo}} - {{this.bar}}
  </div>
{{/with}}
```

I hope it helps